# SSL cert does not work with IP address for SAN

Tags: ssl, curl

I am trying to create an SSL certificate for a server which will work internally without giving warnings in Chrome.  I've created it using SAN with multiple Subject Alt Names of localhost and the IP address.  For some reason it works at localhost but it gives an error using the IP address in both `curl` and Chrome.

```
$ curl https://192.168.1.50 
curl: (51) Unable to communicate securely with peer: requested domain name does not match the server's certificate.

$ curl https://localhost
<a href="https://localhost:9090/">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

Checking it on the command-line shows both names under the SAN section, so I'm not sure why this doesn't work:

```
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in server.crt 
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            8d:93:a1:be:d1:03:8f:59
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=California, L=Los Angeles, O=Alt Systems, OU=Internal, CN=Elliott/emailAddress=xxxxxx
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov  5 21:32:19 2019 GMT
            Not After : Mar 19 21:32:19 2021 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=CA, L=Los Angeles, O=Alt Systems, OU=Internal/emailAddress=xxxxxx, CN=alt-pix-la
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b0:53:b6:0b:f0:94:c1:a8:26:93:79:5a:45:86:
                    36:ac:60:c2:40:a2:bf:25:69:90:9f:8b:b9:3f:63:
                    30:ae:48:cc:f9:f0:9d:d4:15:3d:1c:20:bc:29:6f:
                    57:8f:7d:e9:a5:db:2b:2c:ac:1a:6f:6d:b9:17:98:
                    0e:a0:17:1f:3e:28:4e:42:bd:af:2e:54:dd:ec:ff:
                    7b:00:a5:ed:59:97:8a:6f:95:04:c9:eb:3a:6c:ec:
                    9e:c9:7e:12:ee:ce:cc:be:b7:c1:d3:fe:f6:cf:1d:
                    0d:68:07:68:52:7a:30:5f:f1:29:36:64:b2:a5:e8:
                    5e:a7:f9:75:ab:4b:aa:4b:12:aa:44:59:a3:df:18:
                    45:81:52:b1:4d:00:a4:f2:eb:7e:0d:3e:05:f9:94:
                    1a:aa:e4:2e:9a:ee:0c:59:91:b9:63:f3:5d:98:3b:
                    32:4e:f7:1b:47:e5:a7:54:5c:ba:75:9b:88:09:07:
                    cc:93:06:c3:8a:76:78:83:98:69:1a:8b:e2:fd:cf:
                    70:51:35:09:ba:67:ca:c1:81:f4:65:72:0a:15:7a:
                    12:2d:bc:65:04:7f:b8:c3:22:2b:79:8d:9a:62:54:
                    d2:89:3f:4a:02:72:36:27:6c:ad:50:4d:96:e5:a1:
                    df:8b:fe:51:0b:67:1b:44:4e:57:fc:bb:d7:1d:77:
                    9f:c3
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:BC:39:94:F0:DC:DF:5D:8E:12:E1:DA:5F:8F:7C:C8:02:B4:0E:19:19

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:localhost, DNS:192.168.1.50
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         54:8e:98:93:53:c2:af:fc:b7:03:5c:6d:d3:7d:9a:d9:2f:99:
         ac:29:dc:0f:02:55:36:9e:70:57:68:df:27:5f:5e:a8:43:05:
         ff:a4:7e:bd:15:99:ff:aa:67:35:93:90:35:e0:e7:20:b4:77:
         7c:bf:6f:29:13:46:fc:56:81:58:60:67:14:ae:a1:1b:44:80:
         92:81:7f:ed:5c:bc:75:36:a9:11:52:9b:28:e1:18:d6:a4:17:
         35:13:6c:bd:be:64:db:70:a5:d4:7f:3e:16:26:73:f9:27:ed:
         7b:03:44:b3:59:2d:53:8d:e2:77:f1:6d:8d:21:c0:d0:2c:96:
         27:0c:c6:4e:6f:63:35:61:3e:b5:62:05:88:76:b5:99:ca:7d:
         64:f9:6b:f4:9b:18:8e:3a:77:82:59:d2:13:c0:14:3c:0a:dc:
         8d:82:38:ca:af:e9:43:06:83:ae:6e:4f:73:29:1d:0a:da:91:
         ea:72:f4:26:f3:59:98:8d:ca:1a:ad:19:17:fd:bb:9f:62:bf:
         85:e0:12:bd:9b:93:26:73:2b:9a:77:ff:c4:34:29:25:fc:c7:
         13:8f:94:b3:28:d7:79:dc:54:57:6c:3d:01:f0:37:5c:a9:28:
         23:13:89:7b:c5:63:51:eb:fc:ad:37:d1:31:cf:f4:2f:8c:9c:
         5f:35:07:79
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're using the wrong SAN type – only actual domain *names* are allowed in "DNS" type SANs; for IP addresses there is the "iPAddress" type (`[7] OCTET STRING`).

For OpenSSL you can use:

```
subjectAltName=IP:192.168.1.50

subjectAltName=IP:2001:db8:1234::4567
```

Comment: Thank you!  Just figured this out as you were typing.  I was going to delete the question but now that you've answered I will leave it.

Comment: @ElliottB oh my god, thankfully you didn't delete it, this just saved me

Answer (score 5):

You have to add your IP Address to SAN.
This code working for me. Add your IP Address like this.

```
[alternate_names]
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Where did you add this?

Comment: Yes for which tool is this?

Answer (score 0):

End-To-End example using OpenSSL:
You need to create a config named openssl-san.cnf (Taken from: https://help.bizagi.com/bpm-suite/en/index.html?subjectaltname_support.htm):

```
[ req ]

default_bits           = 4096

distinguished_name     = req_distinguished_name

req_extensions         = req_ext

 

[ req_distinguished_name ]

countryName            = Country Name (2 letter code)

stateOrProvinceName    = State or Province Name (full name)

localityName           = Locality Name (eg, city)

organizationName       = Organization Name (eg, company)

commonName             = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)

 

# Optionally, specify some defaults.
countryName_default           = [Country]
stateOrProvinceName_default   = [State]
localityName_default           = [City]
0.organizationName_default     = [Organization]
organizationalUnitName_default = [Organization unit]
emailAddress_default           = [Email]

 

[ req_ext ]

subjectAltName = @alt_names

 

[alt_names]

DNS.1   = [DNS1]

DNS.2   = [DNS2]

IP.1    = [IP Adddress]
```

And then execute this command to create a key and a certificate-signing-request(csr):

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.key -out keycsr.csr -config openssl-san.cnf
```

To verify the CSR you created do:

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in keycsr.csr
```

You can then sign the CSR yourself, pass it to a CA to sign, etc.